# How can this be?

Tags: riddle, real

I was driving on the highway and saw a car with the following sign: "Caution: blind driver". I checked and the sign was describing true events. How can this be possible?

Comment: Is [lateral-thinking] appropriate for a [real] puzzle? haha. I was thinking to add one since the format of the question is similar to common [lateral-thinking] riddles. But probably not.

Comment: I seem to remember seeing that meme too. I think the text on the van actually said "blind man driving". Works better that way, IMO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The driver was driving blinds (for delivery to install on windows).

Comment: or was the chauffeur for [this guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_Blind).

Comment: Yes that's correct! This actually happened to me today. Unfortunately I couldn't take a photo of the car :)

Answer (score 6):

> The sign was a joke, and the driver was not blind.

or

> The sign was true, and the driver was breaking the law.

or

> The sign was a joke, and the car was parked.

or

> The driver was "blind" according to legal or other criteria, but was capable of driving with glasses.

or

> The car was driven by a basilisk, and the sign was telling people to blind the basilisk, to avoid being turned to stone.

or

> You yourself were lying when you told us about it, and the sign actually said "Proud parent of a Plurpton Middle School honors student".

or

> Plurpton Elementary.

Comment: Some interesting answers here. I added some more information to the puzzle.

Comment: "The driver was 'blind' according to legal or other criteria, but was capable of driving with glasses."  It is (at least theoretically) possible in the UK to be both registered blind (or sight impared) and legally permitted to drive.  For example, see  [here](https://www.dvla-contact-number.co.uk/can-blind-people-drive/) and [here](https://www.rnib.org.uk/your-eyes/navigating-sight-loss/registering-as-sight-impaired/the-criteria-for-certification/).

Answer (score 5):

> The blind driver was behind the wheel of a [self-driving car](https://mag.toyota.co.uk/blind-man-drives-googles-toyota-prius/).

Comment: Would they really be the *driver*, then?